# What is known (or can be deduced with a high degree of certainty) about the distribution of uranium on Mars?

Tags: mars, nuclear

How difficult should we expect it to be to find minable uranium on Mars? What regions of Mars would we most expect to find it in? Is there anything we know about the geology of Mars that would present particular problems to finding and exploiting uranium deposits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find any free papers with the details, but according to the abstract to  ["Solving the Martian meteorite age paradox with a widespread
Uranium-rich reservoir on Mars" - Bellucci, et al.](http://meetingorganizer.copernicus.org/EGU2015/EGU2015-9413.pdf), there is some evidence for a crustal, widespread Uranium-rich reservoir on Mars. By widespread, they mean that it spans the Northern and Southern hemispheres. By rich, they mean 2.4 times greater abundance than that inferred from other meteorites. It is my understanding that the other meteorites imply that Earth has twice as much uranium as Mars, so this new evidence would seem to put uranium abundance on Mars in the same ballpark as Earth.